# Error about dynamic countdown redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an javascript to redirect to another page after countdown 10 seconds, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help to fix the problem?

```
<body>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script type ="text/javascript" src ="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var number = 10;
            var url = 'http://localhost/rms/index.php/';

            function countdown() {
                setTimeout(countdown,1000);
                $('#title1').html("Redirecting in " + number + " seconds");
                number --;

                if(number<0) {
                    window.location = url;
                    number = 0;
                }
            }
            countdown();
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
   <div id="title1"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6xZQE/ . Your code example does not isolate the problem, on the contrary - it works. Please consider creating a code sample that illustrates your problem.

Comment: whether jQuery is present in the directory... check your browser console

Comment: It should works. You probably have a problem with jquery path. Check console for error.

Comment: Also check if you've installed some addon that blocks JavaScript redirects (e.g. Firefox's Noscript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everybody wrote in the comments, it should work. Try to replace

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="jquery.js"></script>
```

with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

In this case you don't have to worry about your jquery.js file, which could be missing or corrupted.

I have one note to your code. Are you aware of that you call window.location = url; two times?
If its just a regular countdown with redirect I will put the setTimeout call in if statement which will prevent calling it twice.